# arrayo object not read in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am getting a json from an API with the following format:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "actividad": "Proyecto X"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "actividad": "Proyecto Y"
}
]
```

when I get the json I use .map and .push to build a new array of objects inside javascript, this is so that a function that expects an array of objects can perform its task, but it happens that for the function the array is empty or invalid for some strange reason. using .log () with the array it turns out to be in the correct format, however when I declare the same object within javascript as constant it works.

I thought it was my mistake but the same thing happens in both React and Jquery (lol, I got desperate and went for "easy" but the error persists and they are different libraries)

jquery:

```
  var $table = $('#table')
  const actividades = []

  $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/Proyecto",
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(res) {          
       res.map(elem => {
        actividades.push({"id":elem["id"],"actividad":elem["actividad"]})
       })
      }
    });
    console.log(actividades)

  $(function() {        
    $table.bootstrapTable({ //this method need the array 
      data: actividades
})
```

React:

```
import React from 'react'
import { TreeTable, TreeState } from 'cp-react-tree-table'
import './TableTree.css'
import axios from 'axios'
const data =[]
const api = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'http://localhost'
})




class TableTree extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  

   api.get('/Proyecto').then(res => {

     res.data.map(elem => {
       data.push({data:{id:elem["id"],actividad:elem["actividad"]}});
     })
     console.log(data)
   })
   this.state = {
     treeValue: TreeState.create(data) //This method need the array
   };
   
}

render() {// other task but is not important}...
```

Update:

I found this behavior un both case, I use .push to add a new value at the end of the assignments within the api call and of course at the end of the api call and strangely it is the only value read! it should be noted that all values have exactly the same structure (I attach images of the log)

react  [image](https://ibb.co/G389pbj) :

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
   api.get('/Proyecto').then(res => {
     res.data.map(elem => {
       data.push({data:{actividad:elem["actividad"]}})
       return null
     })

     
   })
  data.push(
    {
      "data": {
        "actividad": "Proyecto Z"
      }
    }
  )
   console.log(data)
   this.state = {
     treeValue: TreeState.create(data)
   };
   
}
```

jquery [image](https://ibb.co/02VxNcG) :

```
      $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost/Proyecto",
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(res) {          
       res.map(elem => {
        actividades.push(
          {
            "id":elem.id,
            "actividad":elem.actividad
          }
          
        )
        return null
       })
      }
    });

    console.log(actividades)
    actividades.push(        
      {
        "id":3,
        "actividad":"Proyecto Z"              
      }
    )
```

Comment: You need to understand async behavior in javascript. In case of jQuery your initialize method invoked before the API response. Move the   $table.bootstrapTable({ /
      data: actividades inside success block and it will work.

Comment: thanks butt isn't woring, the same problem

Comment: As per bootstrap table definition , you need to pass columns as well along with data.
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
  columns: [{
    field: 'id',
    title: 'Item ID'
  }, {
    field: 'name',
    title: 'Item Name'
  }, {
    field: 'price',
    title: 'Item Price'
  }],
  data: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Item 1',
    price: '$1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Item 2',
    price: '$2'
  }]
})

Comment: They are defined in another section and it works, the only problem is that it does not read the array formed by .map and .push

Comment: update main thread please feel free to check to understand what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor is synchronous, so state is set to, likely, undefined data (*actually, I see now data would just be the empty array (`[]`)*). It doesn't wait for the `api.get` Promise to resolve to set the initial state.

Move the state population to a react lifecycle method; you probably want to fetch/initialize your data when the component mounts. Array.prototype.map also needs to return a value, not issue side-effects like pushing into another array, use Array.prototype.forEach for that.

```
class TableTree extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
    this.state = {
      treeValue: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    api.get('/Proyecto').then(res => {
       const data = res.data.map(elem => ({
         data: {
           id: elem.id,
           actividad: elem.actividad,
         },
       }));
       this.setState({ treeValue: TreeState.create(data) });
     })
  }

  render() {
    // use null guard checks on `this.state.treeValue` to prevent
    // access of undefined/null errors

    // other task but is not important
  }
```

Comment: I am trying to use this but it still does not work, however there is a somewhat strange behavior, use .push () outside the ajax call and curiously it is the value of that push is the only one that recognizes the method and when using .log with the array also the values assigned in the ajax call appear

Comment: @JaviD.Bargz What and where are you trying to push anything? And also what and where are you logging a value?

Comment: @JaviD.Bargz Don't fetch data or make any asynchronous calls in the constructor, this is what the component lifecycle methods are for. I'm guessing that you are only seeing `{ "data": { "actividad": "Proyecto Z" } }` in the console log? It's because the `constructor` runs synchronously, by the time the Promise resolves, the `data.push` and `console.log(data)` have already executed and the function likely has already returned.

Comment: update main thread please feel free to check to understand what i mean

Comment: @JaviD.Bargz I think I completely understand what you are saying. Your code is functioning 100% exactly as you've coded it. (1) constructor (2) `api.get` (3) data.push (4) console.log (5) define state (6) constructor return .... (future tick) `api.get` resolves and does stuff but it doesn't matter since the constructor is already finished.

Comment: Exactly the same behavior if I create a method for the api call and include it in render () and not in the constructor, without forgetting the method that requests the array: TreeState.create (data), which I also include in render ( ) I also emphasize that this behavior happens exactly the same in jquery

Comment: @JaviD.Bargz Right. If you keep doing similar bad patterns then you should expect similar bad results. The `render` lifecycle function is to be considered a pure function, so don't do side-effects like make asynchronous calls, and you ***definitely*** don't update state. I am starting to feel like you're putting us on. Have you tried my suggested solution? Do you have some *running* demo/codesandbox of your code we could just examine?